# Why doesn't get_post_thumbnail function output the url of the thumbnail?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am making a new wordpress theme while working with header slider (i used BXslider) i stuck on inline css thing
I wanna use this code 
http://jsfiddle.net/0nj2ry4n/1/

However, I am unable to use the_post_thumbnail($size) inline css background

```
<li style='background-image: url(the_post_thumbnail($size));'>
```

my code is

```
while($slider->have_posts()): $slider->the_post();
    $myimg = get_post_thumbnail('myslider');

    echo "<li class='featured-post'  style='background-image: url('$myimg');'>";
    echo "</li>";
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
echo "</ul>";
```

*** Updates ***

now if i tried $myimg=the_post_thumbnail_url('myslider'); got this type of html and still i didnt figure it out how to solve this.

```
<ul class="slider slides" style="width: auto; position: relative;">
http://localhost/demo/myweb/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/AAC-CAREERS2-1349x499.jpg
<li class="featured-post" style="background-image: url(&quot;&quot;); float: none; list-style: outside none none; position: absolute; width: 1583px; z-index: 50; display: block;" ');'="">
```

Comment: This is a Wordpress question. You should be using the Wordpress stack.

Comment: @Cam There are 111,000 questions tagged with `Wordpress` here already.  One more won't hurt.

Comment: And I am sure 111,000 people werent aware that there was a WordPress stack... Knowledge is power my friend.

Comment: @Cam There's more knowledge (and more power?) about WP here on SO than there is on wordpress.stackexchange.com.  110k questions to 75k.  No reason to live in the ghetto when the city is thriving.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong function.  [get_post_thumbnail('myslider')](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) returns html, not an image url string.

You want [the_post_thumbnail_url( $size );](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) It echos out the url, so you won't be able to store it in a variable.  Use it inline like so.

```
while($slider->have_posts()): $slider->the_post();
    echo '<li class="featured-post"  style="background-image: url(' . the_post_thumbnail_url('myslider'); . '">';
    echo "</li>";
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: i tried what you said and update my question with what html i got, can you solve this?

Comment: Ah... sorry.  I forgot that the_post_thumbnail_url() echos out the url rather than returning a string.